# Type Casting In Groovy

Tags: groovy

I have two questions.

I did the following code to find the ASCII value of `$` :

```
def a = "\$"
def b = (int)a 
println b //prints 36
```

Well I'm happy with the answer. But when I tried to do it in reverse like this, I found I'm    missing something :

```
def a = 36
String b = a
println b // getting output only 36
```

#### Question 1:

So my first question is why it prints `36` and why not `$`? Am I wrong here?

Well if the same first code block is re-written as:

```
    def a = "\$"
    def b = a as int
    println b
```

If I run this program I get an error like this :

```
Caught: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "$"
    at T.run(T.groovy:2)
```

Even though I'm trying to do the same as before. I'm getting an error.

#### Question 2:

So why does the `as` keyword doesn't work here and does `def a = (int)b` is **not equal to** to `def a = b as int`? Explain me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

when you cast a string to int it's ok while you have one char in it, so we can say you cast a char to int, when you try to cast int to a string i think it uses toString method or something like that. Try to cast 36 to char and you'll see your '$'

Comment: Yes it works, But what about the answer for my second question?

Comment: The 'as' keyword calls the asType method internally which I believe will then try to parse the String as a number, and $ is not a number